# Add to Cart button in Magento 2.1

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, product, cart, addtocart

I tried with **button add to cart** and it not working,

> app/code/Moo/Custom/view/product.phtml

```
<?php 
$product = $this->getData('product');
$postDataHelper = $this->helper('Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper');
$postData = $postDataHelper->getPostData($block->getAddToCartUrl($product),
['product' => $product->getEntityId()]);

<button class="action description-button" data-post='<?php echo $postData; ?>'
<type="button" title="<?php echo __('Add to cart') ?>">
    <span><?php echo __('Add to cart') ?></span>
</button>
```

`data-post` button have action is null ? It look like :

```
data-post="{"action":null,"data":{"product":"7","uenc":"aHR0cDovLzUyLjE4My4yNi45OC9hcmR6YW5fc3VwZXJtYXJrZXQvaW5kZXgvbG9hZHByb2R1Y3Qv"}}"
```

**Please help me, why it not work?**

Comment: please share your block code.

Answer (score 1):

Create form in your template file and pass action for the same .Also you need to pass formkey .

**Try below code :**

```
<form  data-role="tocart-form" action="<?php echo $block->getAddToCartUrl($_item); ?>" method="post">            
<?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
<button type="submit" title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Cart')); ?>" class="action tocart primary" style="float:right;margin-left: 10px;">
<span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */echo __('Add to Cart'); ?></span>
</button>
</form>
```

Comment: thank, but it not work, action form not have url.

Comment: @M.Jack so what you want to achieve ? you want add to cart button in your template file ?

Comment: my issue is product not add to cart. It not work when click add to cart button.Can you hepl me ?

Comment: Yes put my code when you need this button and it will add product to the cart .ultimately you need to take form with the action so paste my code when you need it

Comment: Yes, I use code of you but it not show in minicart and check cart page is empty.

Answer (score 0):

all **data-post** attributes has to be with simple quotation marks